# How do I substitute with a character from the matched text, where the pattern contains a range?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

If I'm using a range in a regex, how can I replace with the character that was matched? For example, lets say I want to find all occurrences of `a` or `b`, and replace them with `aa` or `bb`. Can I do this in a single regex? For example, something like this:

```
:%s/[a-b]/\1\1/g
```

Where `\1` means the first matching character? Can I extend this to several characters? For example converting `camelCase` to `snake_case`. Can I do something like this:

```
%s/[a-z][A-Z]/\1_\2/g
```

Where `\1` is the first matching character and `\2` is the second matching character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using the entire matched text, just use [`&`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s%2F%5C%26):

```
magic   nomagic   action    
  &       \&      replaced with the whole matched pattern            s/\&
 \&        &      replaced with &
```

So:

```
%s/[a-b]/&&/g
```

For using the matched text in parts, use [regex groups](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28):

```
\(\)    A pattern enclosed by escaped parentheses.      /\( /\(\) /\)
        E.g., "\(^a\)" matches 'a' at the start of a line.
        E51 E54 E55 E872 E873

\1      Matches the same string that was matched by     /\1 E65
        the first sub-expression in \( and \). {not in Vi}
        Example: "\([a-z]\).\1" matches "ata", "ehe", "tot", etc.
\2      Like "\1", but uses second sub-expression,      /\2
   ...                                                  /\3
\9      Like "\1", but uses ninth sub-expression.       /\9
        Note: The numbering of groups is done based on which "\(" comes first
        in the pattern (going left to right), NOT based on what is matched
        first.
```

So:

```
%s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1_\2/g
```

Or more conveniently, [enabling magic](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic):

```
%s/\v([a-z])([A-Z])/\1_\2/g
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: May want to use `\l` to lowercase the next letter in the substitution. e.g. `%s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1_\l\2/g`. See `:h s/\l` for more information.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem see Peter's suggestion, it should be useful for the camelcase conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change from camelCase style to snake_case style via the [Abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin

```
%s/\<\l\+\u\w\+/\=Abolish.snakecase(submatch(0))/g
```

Abolish also provides "Coerce" mappings:

- `crc` - coerce to camelCase
- `crs` - coerce to snake_case
- `crm` - coerce to MixCased
- `cru` - coerce to UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE
- `cr-` - coerce to dashed-case

There is Vimcasts eposide on use Abolish: [Smart search with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/smart-search-with-subvert/)

For more help see:

```
:h /\<
:h /\l
:h /\u
:h sub-replace-expression
```